# Modify driver from within another driver?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, drivers

It's possible to modify most of an object's properties arbitrarily in a driver.

For example, the below driver, when placed on an object's X location transform, will copy that object's Y location to its Z location on every frame:

`[0, self.location.__setitem__(2, self.location[1])][0]`

Is there a known way to do the same when the property that is to be modified belongs to another driver?

E.G. The below code works to set the target of a variable on the driver of an object's X location when evaluated in the console, but not when evaluated in a driver on its rotation channel:

`[setattr(self.animation_data.drivers.find('location', index=0).driver.variables["var"].targets[0], 'id', self),0][-1]`

Comment: Hm. Setting constraint properties from inside the driver doesn't work either, and for that matter, changing `.location` affects `.matrix_world` but doesn't actually affect `.location`... It seems that evaluation and thus assignments for drivers are probably done in a restricted context that gets used to update matrices and such used for display/rendering, but cannot manually affect scene data.

Comment: I don't think there's any restricted context, and since you're already hacking (not really using drivers like you're supposed to), you should be able to do pretty much anything - though you might be better off using an autorun script than drivers like that. Also, maybe the driver appears not to work, because it's being evaluated **after** the driver it modifies has already been evaluated (so-called race condition)?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady The first example driver I posted affects `.matrix_world`, but not `.location`, so there does seem to be some separation in how drivers are evaluated that restricts what they can affect. (It's changes to  `.location` presumably get used by Blender to compute `.matrix_world`, but don't directly make it to the scene data.) I fully expect race conditions on single frames with this abuse, but I still should be able to see the changes in the UI or Python console if they're actually working.

Answer (score 1):

`self` in a driver is not the original object you as a user operate on; it's an evaluated copy instead. In order to access the original object so the changes to it aren't discarded, either use a full path, or `original` property. So your example:

- `[setattr(self.animation_data.drivers.find('location', index=0).driver.variables["var"].targets[0], 'id', self),0][-1]`

becomes

- `[setattr(self.original.animation_data.drivers.find('location', index=0).driver.variables["var"].targets[0], 'id', self.original),0][-1]`